# Debounce 'object doesn't support this action' in IE11

Tags: reactjs, lodash, internet-explorer-11, debouncing

This error is occurring within a React app:

- Function calls `componentWillUpdateProps`, which then calls another function that uses lodash's `_.debounce(`
- In other browsers, the code works fine, but in IE11, it throws an error: `Object doesn't support this action`, followed by a type error `Unable to get property 'localName' of undefined or null reference`, the second error pointing to code generated at runtime

I have isolated the error and am sure that it is the use of `_.debounce` that causes the error.

My question is, does IE11 not support `debounce`?

Comment: From the [documentation of Lodash](https://lodash.com/), it supports IE 11. So I think the issue is not because IE's support for  `_.debounce`. What is the code in your `_.debounce` function? Besides, it could be better if you provide [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can reproduce the issue. You could use some online code editor like [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) to show the sample.

Comment: After further investigation I have found that lodash is not the issue, but a custom event is that IE does not support. I will clarify in an answer soon

Comment: It's so great that you have found the solution! You could post it as an answer and mark your answer as an accepted answer when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the issue was not related to Debounce, but, because of the code called `new Event`, which IE11 does not support. `document.createEvent` can instead be used as a workaround